# Some questions regarding the $L^2$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, borel-sets

Let $(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})$ be the Borel space associated to $\mathbb{R}$.
Also, let
$$\mathcal{L}^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})=\bigg\{f:(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})\,\,\Big|\,\int f^2\,\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty\bigg\}$$
be the set of all (real-valued) square-integrable (measurable) functions with respect to (the measure) $\mu$.

Then can we say the following?

1. When the Lebesgue space $L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ is viewed as a set, it is defined as the quotient set:
   $$L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})_\text{set}:=\mathcal{L}^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\,\,/\sim,$$
   where $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{L}^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ such that:
   $$f\sim g\quad:\Leftrightarrow\quad f-g=0\,\text{ $\mu$-almost everywhere.}$$
   Is this the definition of $L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ as a set?
2. If so, what does '$\mu$-almost everywhere' actually mean in the above definition?
   Some authors seem to imply that (but of course I may be wrong with this interpretation):
   $$f(\xi)\neq g(\xi)\quad\Rightarrow\quad \mu(\xi)=0$$
   when they say that if $f=g$ then $f$ and $g$ differ only on a set of measure zero. Here $\xi\in\Xi$.
   However, for this to work, we require that $\{\xi\}$ is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra $\boldsymbol{\Xi}$ to make sure that $\{\xi\}\mapsto\mu(\xi)$ is well-defined.
   This therefore imposes a hidden requirement on the definition of $\boldsymbol{\Xi}$ (which I don't like).
   Or is this the correct interpretation?
   $$f-g=0\,\text{ $\mu$-almost everywhere}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\int (f-g)^2\,\mathrm{d}\mu=0.$$
3. The reason why we want to define such an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathcal{L}^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ is that if we equip $L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ with the bilinear map:
   $$\langle\,\cdot\,,\cdot\,\rangle:L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\times L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}\quad:\Leftrightarrow\quad\langle f,g\rangle=\int fg\,\mathrm{d}\mu,$$
   then $\langle\,\cdot\,,\cdot\,\rangle$ qualifies as an inner product on $L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ because it satisfies the positive-definite condition of an inner product.
   Is this the correct motivation?
4. $L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ is by definition a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and no further structure is assumed on $L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})_\text{set}$.
5. If nothing is said, all (equivalence classes of) measurable functions in $L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ are always assumed to be maps from $(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi})$ into the Borel measurable space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})$, aren't they?

(Disclaimer: I am not a mathematician but an engineer studying functional analysis; thus, the notation used here may be non-standard or simply incorrect. If that is the case, please let me know. I would appreciate it very much.)

Thank you,
Frederick.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean when you write "...space..is viewed as a set".

Comment: My understanding is that $L^2$ is a vector space by definition. So, by $L^2$ viewed as a set I mean the space $L^2$ without any structure defined on the underlying set (i.e. after removing in this case the vector addition operation and the scalar multiplication operation from the space). Pretty sure that there is a better way to say that, but couldn't find a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning (2), we say that $f = g$ $\mu$-a.e. (or $f - g = 0$ $\mu$-a.e.) if $\mu(\Theta \setminus \{f - g = 0\}) = 0$.  This makes sense as long as $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions from $(\Theta,\mathbf{\Theta})$ into $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ since then $\{f - g = 0\} \in \mathbf{\Theta}$.

It turns out that this is, in fact, equivalent to the condition $\int_{\Theta} (f - g)^{2} \, d \mu = 0$.  However, this requires that we define the Lebesgue integral, whereas the previous definition I gave is a "primitive notion."

The answer to (3) is "yes."  However, it's a bit like saying "We define $\mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't a complete metric space."  That may technically contain some kernel of truth, but there are "philosophical" or "emotional" reasons why we would like to work with $\mathbb{R}$ in addition to $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. we might like to believe that a "continuum" or a "line" has some physical significance).  Similarly, in the settings in which measure theory is relevant, it tends to be natural to think of two functions that agree $\mu$-almost everywhere to be the same.  ($\mu$ sees them the same way, let's say; or we added "some dust" to one of the functions, which is irrelevant.)

Concerning (5), yes, technically, an element of $L^{2}(\Theta,\mathbf{\Theta},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ is an equivalence class of measurable functions mapping $(\Theta,\mathbf{\Theta})$ into $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$.  The one caveat is nothing is lost or gained if we replace $(\Theta,\mathbf{\Theta})$ by $(\Theta,\mathbf{\Theta}_{\mu})$, where $\mathbf{\Theta}_{\mu}$ is the completion of $\mu$ with respect to $\mathbf{\Theta}$.  Hence, formally, it might be better to incorporate completeness of $(\Theta,\mathbf{\Theta},\mu)$ into the definition of $L^{2}(\Theta,\mathbf{\Theta},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ at the outset.  Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm not aware of any instances where this matters.  (It's a bit like the space $\mathcal{L}(V)$ of continuous linear operators on a normed space $V$.  $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is unchanged if $V$ is replaced by its completion.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. In your second paragraph, you seem to indicate that there is a way to check that $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e. without using the Lebesgue integral. If there exists such a way, do you think it is possible to redefine $\mathcal{L}^2$ (as displayed above) without calling the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Maybe, but that's beside the point.  The notion "$f = g$ $\mu$-a.e." is a statement about measurable functions; the integral need not be involved.  (For instance, $f$ and $g$ do not need to be in $\mathcal{L}^{2}$ for us to make such a statement.)

Comment: In his celebrated book "Real and Complex Analysis - 3rd Edition", Rudin makes an observation on Page 28 (third paragraph) regarding the completion of a measure space. He says that every measure if not complete can be completed, that more often than not measures are already complete, but that there are exceptions like in the proof of Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

1. I am assuming that by ${\cal L}^2$ you mean the square integrable functions and by $L^2$ you mean the equivalence classes. Both of these are sets and you have $L^2 = {\cal L}^2 / \sim$. (Both are vector spaces with the appropriate definitions of $+,\cdot$.)
2. $f=g $ $[\mu]$ ae. means there is a set of measure zero (null set) $N$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \notin N$.
3. The reason for the equivalence classes is so that $f \mapsto \sqrt{\int |f|^2d \mu}$ is a norm
   rather than a seminorm.
4. $L^2$ is a set, I am not sure how you distinguish the two.
5. No. An element of $L^2$ is the equivalence class of (square integrable) measureable functions $\Xi \to \mathbb{R}$.

In many situations one can be sloppy about the distinction, just as we rarely think of real numbers as equivalence classes. Sometimes one needs to be careful, for example, to define the $\sup$ norm (for $L^\infty$) of support of an equivalence class.

Comment: Thanks for the response. (1 and 4) I guess our disagreement is coming from the fact that there are at least two ways to define a vector space symbolically. Namely, either we write $V:=(V,+,\cdot\,)$ with the understanding that the 1st $V$ is the name of the vector space and the 2nd $V$ is the name of the underlying set, or by way of omitting the structure defined on the set, like it is the case for: "let $(V,+,\cdot\,)$ be a vector space..." versus "let $V$ be a vector space...". The notation I am using in the thread is the former, whereas the one I think you are using is the latter.

Comment: (2) Thanks. That answers my question.
(3) Thanks again, I think that answers my question as well. However, if we start from the aforementioned bilinear map, don't we have to ensure that such a map is indeed an inner product so that the 'induced norm' is a norm and not a seminorm.
(5) To check that $f$ is a measurable function it is required to define a $\sigma$-algebra on the domain of $f$ and another $\sigma$-algebra on the codomain of $f$. My question was, if nothing is said, can we assume that the $\sigma$-algebra defined on the codomain of $f$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Well, the notation $V(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ can be viewed in (at least) two ways, one as a collection of objects satisfying some property (such as square integrability) and the other a way of identifying the objects involved (the set, the $\sigma$-field, etc). I suppose I view it as both to some degree.

Comment: For (3), the map is not an inner product unless you deal with equivalence classes. Also, you can work with either the norm or inner product, as you can define the inner product in terms of the norm (polarisation identities). Generally in analysis (as opposed to measure theory) the Borel $\sigma$-field generated by the open sets is the 'default' one.

Comment: Is the answer to (5) really "no"?  It might be worth explaining how you are contradicting what was in the original question or my answer.  (Perhaps it is a wording issue.)

Comment: @PeterMorfe An element of $L^2$ is an equivalence class and each element of the equivalence class is a function $\Xi \to \mathbb{R}$. If I read your answer correctly, that is what you are saying, but the statement in the question is ambiguous.